# Display Checkboxes on Click of a button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button Resend , and on click of it , the checkboxes get enable against the following:

- `id="AlertSent"`
- `id="AlertNotSent"`
- `id="AlertInProgress"`

Now the DIV Code for Above mentioned DIVS is as below

```
<div class="span9">
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="enableCheckBox" class ="span12">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1"/>
        </div>
        <div id="AlertSent" class="span12">
            <label><spring:message code='alert.sent' />:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="enableCheckBox" class ="span12">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox2" name="checkbox2"/>
        </div>
        <div id="AlertNotSent" class="span12">
            <label><spring:message code='alert.not.sent'/>:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div id="enableCheckBox" class ="span12">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox3" name="checkbox3" class="required" />
        </div>
        <div id="AlertInProgress" class="span12">
            <label> <spring:message code='alert.in.progress' />:</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The button Code for Resend and Done is

```
<input type="button" value="button" id="resend"/>
<input type="button" value="button" id="done"/>
```

The JQuery Code is

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict();
j$(document).ready(function() {   
    var resendbtn = j$('#resend');
    var allChkBox = j$('input[name="enableCheckBox"]');

    var verifyChecked = function() {
        if ! $('#resend').click {
            allChkBox.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            allChkBox.removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    };

    verifyChecked();

    resendbtn.change(verifyChecked);
});
```

The requirement is on click of Resend, the checkboxes appear against above DIVS (`AlertSent`, `AlertNotSent` and `AlertInProgress`), and the Resend button Becomes Done, and if a User unchecks all the checkboxes then the Done Button becomes Resend again.

How do I write a JQuery/JavaScript code to achieve above?

Please suggest

Comment: Could you offer a jsfiddle with the code so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what you want here, but perhaps this will get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZqH7B/

to handle showing the checkboxes:

```
$("#resend").on( 'click', function () {
    $('.enableCheckBox').css('visibility', 'inherit');
    $(this).hide().next().show();
    $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', true);
});
```

to handle uncheck behavior:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on( 'change', function() {
    var num = $('input:checked').length;
    if ( num == 0 ) { $('#resend').show().next().hide(); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following code:

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="chk">
<input type="button" value="Resend" class="toggle">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".chk").prop("checked","checked");
    $(".chk").css('display','none');
    $(".toggle").click(function(){
        $(".chk").css('display','block');
        $(".chk").prop("checked","checked");
        $(this).val("Done");
    });
    $(".chk").change(function(){
        var all = $(".chk").length;
        var chked = $(".chk").not(":checked").length;
        if(all == chked){
            $(".chk").css('display','none');
            $(".toggle").val("Resend");
        }
    })
});
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QHs4F/)